# Convert 5 digit int value to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a 5 integer time to a real time in SQL. The code is below, out put sample line also below. What I hope to eventually do is subtract the end time and start time to get a total time, and then sum them together and create a trigger that says when an employee hits a 30,35,and 40 hour mark, send an email to alert someone. This is for overtime purposes.

```
SELECT empl_numb
        ,start_time
        ,end_time
        ,dateadd(d, trans_rdat + 5843, 0) AS theday
  FROM ei30
 WHERE empl_numb = '12345' -- and DATEADD(d, TRANS_RDAT + 5843 ,0)
    AND shift_break_code NOT LIKE 'L'
    AND shift_break_code NOT LIKE 'S'
 ORDER BY dateadd(d, trans_rdat + 5843, 0) DESC;
```

Results:

```
    EMPL_NUMB   START_TIME  END_TIME    TheDay
    12345       01257       01714       2013-12-12 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What do your integers represent?

Comment: Do you have the option of storing `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` as `time` values instead of what I'm assuming are `string`s?

Comment: The integers represent time the time in military format (just remove the leading 0)

Comment: I can convert the values and have them be whatever I want. Whatever makes sense and is easiest for subtracting time values to get a total # of hours worked

Comment: SQL Server has a built-in native datatype called `time` for just these purposes. Do you have the option of using that in your table instead of `varchar`s? It would make this easier. It should certainly be possible to convert a `varchar` to a `time`, but it may simplify things for you if you can use the `time` datatype directly.

Comment: Integers don't have leading `0`s, so what is the *actual* format the data is stored in?

Comment: I don't have the option to change how the data is stored, but I can pull and create new tables as I see fit. The current data type is CHAR(5) for this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically good practice to store dates and times with the appropriate datatype.

You can use `DATEADD()` and modulus division for the time portion:

```
DECLARE @time INT = 1234
SELECT DATEADD(minute,@time%100,DATEADD(hour,(@time/100),CAST('' AS TIME)))
```

Edit:  Since it's actually a `CHAR(5)` you can use `SUBSTRING()` and concatenation:

```
DECLARE @time CHAR(5) = '01234'
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@time,2,2)+':'+RIGHT(@time,2) AS TIME)
```

Comment: OP's source datatype is CHAR(5)

Comment: @MichaelGunter Missed that, thanks.  The top method will work regardless of datatype, but the substring method might feel better since it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the type of your data, you'll have to perform string manipulation to change the string into a valid `time` format using [`SUBSTRING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), which you can then use the [`CAST`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) or [`CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function on. I don't have a SQL server instance handy, so I'll leave it to you to put these functions together to produce your solution.